# How to run main function Kotlin file on command-line with string array arguments

Tags: kotlin, command-line

i'm trying to run one of .kt files that i have for my side project and I suddenly wanted run my *.kt file that has

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) { 
  ...
}
```

on command-line tool. I did install kotlin compiler, set up the path. All I have to do is to figure out how to pass args parameter through command line and cannot find a way to do that.

I've looked through [kotlin compiler options](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-reference.html) and [how to run kotlin file on command-line](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html#creating-and-running-a-first-application) and it did not help at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just type them after the command:

```
java -jar myjar.jar arg_one arg_two

//OR (After compiling to jars you can specify the main class to run)
kotlin -classpath myjar.jar MyKt 'arg_one' 'arg_two'

//OR
kotlin MyKt 'arg_one' 'arg_two'
```

Then:

```
val argOne = args[0] // "arg_one"
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to compile your file to a JAR:

```
kotlinc filename.kt -include-runtime -d output.jar
```

Then you can run that JAR with `java`:

```
java -jar output.jar argument0 argument1
```